# Has Daniel Bernoulli's 1764 paper on organ pipe acoustics been translated into English?

Tags: physics, acoustics

The full title:
RECHERCHES PHYSIQUES MÉCANIQUES ET ANALYTIQUES SUR LE SON ET SUR LE TONS DES TUYAUX D’ORGUES DIFFÉREMMENT CONSTRUITS

Link to a pdf: https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/011812546

Some excerpts are translated in the 1890 treatise "The Flute" by R. S. Rockstro (Part I, Ch. 4):
[https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~wbc/rockstro/](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Ewbc/rockstro/)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Very unlikely, mathematical papers in French are rarely translated into English. Kergomard refers to the French source only in [Acoustics of Musical Instruments (2016)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Acoustics_of_Musical_Instruments/p_qODAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I keep thinking I’ll fine a thesis that includes it, but hope is fading.